# How to retrieve added files from different OS than Windows on BitLocker decrypted drive

Tags: operating-system, external, hard-drive, bitlocker

I had BitLocker encrypted external HDD that I used on my Mac (with M3 BitLocker Loader). After adding several files I moved back to my Windows PC and decrypted the drive. Now the files that were added on my Mac are no longer there. How can I retrieve my files?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the files weren't available on MAC OS only, otherwise they were still there.. though some of them were damaged